# How do I merge cells in Pandas + Python?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

There is this data:

```py
d1 = {"URL": ["https://example.com/1540"], "data": [2.5, 12.0, 5.0]}
d2 = {"URL": ["https://example.com/4541"], "data": [1.0, 8.0, 0.0]}
```

The main question is how do I combine it so that in **Excel** it's like this:

[image: EXAMPLE IMAGE]

This is all assuming that the **DATA**, can be completely randomly sized.

How do I do this?
I've tried to do something, but the result is just this:

[image: EXAMPLE RESULT IMAGE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) to merge the duplicated values then [`Styler.applymap_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.set_properties.html) with the standard [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS) styles to get the desired Excel spreadsheet format.

Try this :

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = {"URL": ["https://example.com/1540"], "data": [2.5, 12.0, 5.0]}
d2 = {"URL": ["https://example.com/4541"], "data": [1.0, 8.0, 0.0]}

def stylize_df(_):
    return "font-weight: normal; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"

(
    pd.DataFrame([d1, d2])
        .apply(pd.Series.explode)
        .pivot_table(index=["URL", "data"], sort=False)
        .style.applymap_index(stylize_df)
        .to_excel("output_file.xlsx", startrow=-1)
)
```

##### # Output (in Excel) :

[image]

Comment: I've listed below a couple of new conditions and data that the code doesn't work with :(

Comment: Based on your update, does the columns `2`, `1` and `Y` need also to be merged like `URL` ?

Comment: I need to merge all cells that are smaller than the largest column (and since this is a parser, you can't be sure which column will be the largest), and merge normally, i.e. if there are two data cells, then you need to merge so that only 2 cells are left. I will update the post and show you how it should look like.

Comment: I've edited the last post.

Answer (score 0):

Your advice helped, but not completely, I decided to add more data and this happens: [OUTPUT IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQXQ4.png)

In general, I want to get a result like this (I've already corrected it myself): [FIX OUTPUT IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dURMy.png)

Here is a sample code snippet of how this happens in a function:

```py
data = [
    {
        '1': [3.7],
        'X': [3.15],
        '2': [2.26],
        'ТОТАЛЫ': [0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2, 2.25, 2.5, 2.75, 3, 3.25, 3.5, 3.75, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5],
        'БОЛЬШЕ': [1.1, 1.12, 1.14, 1.29, 1.46, 1.6, 1.85, 2.16, 2.43, 2.89, 3.7, 4.1, 4.55, 5.7, 8.6, 9.3, 14.0, 14.0],
        'МЕНЬШЕ': [6.6, 6.0, 5.45, 3.4, 2.66, 2.34, 2.03, 1.71, 1.54, 1.39, 1.25, 1.21, 1.19, 1.13, 1.06, 1.05, 1.01, 1.01],
        'URL': ['https://www.flashscorekz.com/match/G0rn6WE5/#/match-summary/match-summary']
    },
    {
        '1': [2.8],
        'X': [3.15],
        '2': [2.8],
        'ТОТАЛЫ': [0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2, 2.25, 2.5, 2.75, 3, 3.25, 3.5, 3.75, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5],
        'БОЛЬШЕ': [1.09, 1.1, 1.12, 1.27, 1.42, 1.53, 1.74, 2.06, 2.34, 2.73, 3.45, 3.8, 4.1, 5.45, 7.5, 7.0, 11.0, 12.0],
        'МЕНЬШЕ': [7.0, 6.6, 6.0, 3.55, 2.81, 2.46, 2.13, 1.8, 1.6, 1.44, 1.28, 1.24, 1.21, 1.14, 1.08, 1.09, 1.03, 1.02],
        'URL': ['https://www.flashscorekz.com/match/2g49AZK4/#/match-summary']
    },
    {
        '1': [6.2],
        'X': [3.9],
        '2': [1.63],
        'ТОТАЛЫ': [0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2, 2.25, 2.5, 2.75, 3, 3.25, 3.5, 3.75, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5],
        'БОЛЬШЕ': [1.07, 1.08, 1.1, 1.23, 1.36, 1.46, 1.61, 1.92, 2.16, 2.48, 3.05, 3.4, 3.7, 4.7, 6.6, 7.5, 12.0, 12.0],
        'МЕНЬШЕ': [8.0, 7.5, 6.6, 3.9, 3.0, 2.66, 2.33, 1.96, 1.71, 1.52, 1.35, 1.29, 1.25, 1.18, 1.1, 1.08, 1.02, 1.02],
        'URL': ['https://www.flashscorekz.com/match/hdEvqxcM/#/match-summary']
    }
]

index = list(data[0].keys())
df: pd.DataFrame = (pd.DataFrame(data)
   .apply(pd.Series.explode)
   .pivot_table(index=index, sort=False)
   .style.applymap_index(stylize_df)
)
```